# express + mysql : clean code for complex queries

Tags: mysql, express

I am using express with mysql for my api.

This code works fine :

```
exports.addAuthor = function(req, res, next) {  // POST /authors {{{
  let sqlquery = '';
  let a = checkAuthor(req.body);
  if(!a.valid) {
    var myerr = new Error(a.msg);
    myerr.status = 400;
    return next(myerr);
  }
  //
  myPool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    // check if exists first
    sqlquery =  'SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb FROM authors';
    sqlquery += '  WHERE name = "' + a.name + '" AND firstname = "' + a.firstname + '";';
    connection.query(sqlquery, function(err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        connection.release();
        return next(err);
      } else {
        if (rows[0].nb > 0) {
          connection.release();
          let myerr = new Error('This author already exists !');
          myerr.status = 400;
          return next(myerr);
        } else {
          sqlquery =  'INSERT INTO authors (name, firstname)';
          sqlquery += '  VALUES ("' + a.name + '","' + a.firstname + '")';
          connection.query(sqlquery, function(err, rows) {
            connection.release();
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (rows.affectedRows) {
              res.json({name: a.name, firstname: a.firstname, id: rows.insertId});
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
}; // }}}
```

First, I would like to reuse the code to get the id of the author, if it exists, so define one function for that.
Secondly I would like to write simpler and cleaner code as I imagine more complex code with several requests to the DB for future cases. (12 lines only to check if author exists !)

I know it has to deal with asynchronous nature of the Mysql queries.
I read many things but I am still no able to write proper code to acheive that.

Thanks to point me to right way to manage not so simple case.

JPM

---

I think I succeeded to make work some code that was not working yesterday !
I do not know yet if it is the best way however.
I took some piece of code somewhere but I do not remember where (probably here).
Here it is :

```
const execQuery = (sql, params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // {{{
  myPool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) { 
      reject(err); 
    } else {
      connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
          connection.release();
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(rows);
        }
      })
    }
  });
}); // }}}
async function getIDAuthor(a) { // {{{
  sqlquery =  'SELECT id FROM authors';
  sqlquery += '  WHERE name = "' + a.name + '" AND firstname = "' + a.firstname + '"';
  if(a.id) {  // case update name of known author
    sqlquery += '    AND id <> ' + a.id;
  }
  try {
    rows = await execQuery(sqlquery);
    if(rows.length>0) {
      return rows[0].id;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return -1;
  }
} // }}}
exports.addAuthor = async function(req, res, next) {  // POST /authors {{{
  let sqlquery = '';
  let a = checkAuthor(req.body); // {{{
  if(!a.valid) {
    var myerr = new Error(a.msg);
    myerr.status = 400;
    return next(myerr);
  } // }}}
  let ide = await getIDAuthor(a);
  if(ide>0) {
    let myerr = new Error('This author already exists !');
    myerr.status = 400;
    return next(myerr);
  }
  sqlquery =  'INSERT INTO authors (name, firstname)';
  sqlquery += '  VALUES ("' + a.name + '","' + a.firstname + '")';
  try {
    rows = await execQuery(sqlquery);
    if (rows.affectedRows) {
      res.json({name: a.name, firstname: a.firstname, id: rows.insertId});
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
}; // }}}
```

I have not yet checked all possible errors.
Feel free to advise me or correct me if needed.

Comment: You can use ORMs like Sequelize, Bookshelf for writing better queries... more readable queries.

Answer (score 0):

I took code and ideas from https://nemethgergely.com/error-handling-express-async-await/
So it looks now like this:

```
exports.addAuthor = asyncMiddleware(async function(req, res, next) {  // POST /authors {{{
  let sqlquery = '';
  let rows;
  //
  let a = checkAuthor(req.body);
  if(!a.valid) { throw boom.badRequest(a.msg); }
  let ide = await getIDAuthor(a);
  if(ide>0) { throw boom.badRequest('Cet auteur existe déjà !'); }
  //
  sqlquery =  'INSERT INTO authors (name, firstname)';
  sqlquery += '  VALUES ("' + a.name + '","' + a.firstname + '")';
  rows = await execQuery(sqlquery);
  if (rows.affectedRows) {
    res.json({name: a.name, firstname: a.firstname, id: rows.insertId});
  }
}); // }}}
```

---

In fact this does not handle all error cases. Forget it. Still at start point. Grrrrrr.